# How to add extra field in datatable which is not database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables, joomla3.0

I am trying to add `edit` and `delete` button in data table.

I have html

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Theater name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Theater name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_wsmovies&task=addtheatres' ); ?>"
    });
});
```

I tried adding column in `thead` and `tbody` but it is giving me alert saying

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Server returning data

> {"draw":0,"recordsTotal":57,"recordsFiltered":57,"data":[["Tiger","Nixon"],["Garrett","Winters"],["Ashton","Cox"],["Cedric","Kelly"],["Airi","Satou"],["Brielle","Williamson"],["Herrod","Chandler"],["Rhona","Davidson"],["Colleen","Hurst"],["Sonya","Frost"],["Jena","Gaines"],["Quinn","Flynn"],["Charde","Marshall"],["Haley","Kennedy"],["Tatyana","Fitzpatrick"],["Michael","Silva"],["Paul","Byrd"],["Gloria","Little"],["Bradley","Greer"],["Dai","Rios"],["Jenette","Caldwell"],["Yuri","Berry"],["Caesar","Vance"],["Doris","Wilder"],["Angelica","Ramos"],["Gavin","Joyce"],["Jennifer","Chang"],["Brenden","Wagner"],["Fiona","Green"],["Shou","Itou"],["Michelle","House"],["Suki","Burks"],["Prescott","Bartlett"],["Gavin","Cortez"],["Martena","Mccray"],["Unity","Butler"],["Howard","Hatfield"],["Hope","Fuentes"],["Vivian","Harrell"],["Timothy","Mooney"],["Jackson","Bradshaw"],["Olivia","Liang"],["Bruno","Nash"],["Sakura","Yamamoto"],["Thor","Walton"],["Finn","Camacho"],["Serge","Baldwin"],["Zenaida","Frank"],["Zorita","Serrano"],["Jennifer","Acosta"],["Cara","Stevens"],["Hermione","Butler"],["Lael","Greer"],["Jonas","Alexander"],["Shad","Decker"],["Michael","Bruce"],["Donna","Snider"]]}

Can anyone help me solve this issue

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please post code from your attempts and we can help you out in debugging it

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add its HTML in your `DataTable` definition

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_wsmovies&task=addtheatres' ); ?>",
    "columns": [
             {
                "targets": -1,
                "data": null,
                "orderable": false,
                "defaultContent": [ 
                    "<i  class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i>"+
                    "<i  class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i>"]

             }

    ]
} );
```

**DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/evfchh7q/**

Change your table definition as below(Added one more header as you are sending data for two columns + edit button column).

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Theater name</th>
            <th>One more header</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Theater name</th>
            <th>One more header</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: It's not working. I am getting `Processing...` only @PrakashThete

Comment: In console `TypeError: f is undefined
kb()
jquery.dataTables.min.js:27
ga()
jquery.dataTables.min.js:48
m/<()
jquery.dataTables.min.js:93
.each()
jquery-1.12.3.js:370
jQuery.prototype.each()
jquery-1.12.3.js:137
m()
jquery.dataTables.min.js:82
h.fn.DataTable()
jquery.dataTables.min.js:166
<anonymous>
datatable:12
jQuery.Callbacks/fire()
jquery-1.12.3.js:3232
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith()
jquery-1.12.3.js:3362
.ready()
jquery-1.12.3.js:3582
completed()`

Comment: I have added link to demo. Please  have a look.

Comment: You are sending an extra parameter in data like `["Tiger","Nixon"]` either add one more header or remove `"Nixon"` for example from response if not necessary.

Comment: Updated the answer and `JSFiddle` please have a look.